# How to use enumerate function in python to get the count of the iteration in a for loop?

Tags: python, enumerate

```
for idx,server in enumerate(servers ):
print idx
```

This is throwing an error. How to print the count of iterations?

Comment: First of all, you should really fix your indentation so that we know that is not the issue. We also need more information. What is the exception that the code throws? What is servers set to? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
for idx, server in enumerate(servers):
    print(idx)
```

Indentations are important, so put the codeblock at the appropriate depth.